# Laravel Method paginate does not exist

Tags: laravel, methods, pagination

I am trying to paginate Model result, but I am getting "Method paginate does not exist.". Here is my code:

```
$user_dispatches = Dispatch::all()->where('user_id', Auth::id())->paginate(10);
```

I need to get all records where users id equals current authenticated users id. Works well without paginate() method.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You need to remove `all()`:

```
Dispatch::where('user_id', Auth::id())->paginate(10);
```

When you're using `all()` you get all the rows from the table and get a collection. Then you're using collection method `where()` (and not Query Builder method `where()`) and then you're trying to use `paginate()` method on the collection and it doesn't exist.

Comment: Perfect explanation @Alexy Mezenin

Answer (score 109):

Extending a bit Alexey's perfect answer :

> `Dispatch::all()` => Returns a `Collection`
>
> `Dispatch::all()->where()` => Returns a `Collection`
>
> `Dispatch::where()` => Returns a `Query`
>
> `Dispatch::where()->get()` => Returns a `Collection`
>
> `Dispatch::where()->get()->where()` => Returns a `Collection`

You can only invoke "`paginate`" on a `Query`, not on a `Collection`.

And yes, it is totally confusing to have a `where` function for both `Queries` and `Collections`, working as close as they do, but it is what it is.

Comment: nicely explained. Should be marked as a correct answer

Comment: I take this is not the case anymore as DIspatch::paginate() returns a collection and works perfectly

Comment: It might not be the case for latest versions, but not everybody uses the last version of everything.

Answer (score 19):

for use all recorde and pagination , you need use below code :

```
$user_dispatches = Disspath::paginate(25);
```

Answer (score 7):

You need remove method `all()` :

```
$user_dispatches = Dispatch::where('user_id', Auth::id())->paginate(10);
```

Because `all()` return a `Collection` while `paginate()` used a `Builder`

Answer (score 5):

The method `toQuery()` changes a collection to query:

```php
$pacientes = Paciente::get()->toQuery()->paginate(20);
```

Comment: An elegant and simple solution to a tricky problem

Comment: Any reason not to just do `Paciente::paginate(20);` instead?

Answer (score 2):

```
Dispatch::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create own custom class:

```
<?php
namespace App\CustomClasses;

use Illuminate\Container\Container;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class ColectionPaginate
{
    public static function paginate(Collection $results, $pageSize)
    {
        $page = Paginator::resolveCurrentPage('page');
        
        $total = $results->count();

        return self::paginator($results->forPage($page, $pageSize), $total, $pageSize, $page, [
            'path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
            'pageName' => 'page',
        ]);

    }

    /**
     * Create a new length-aware paginator instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Support\Collection  $items
     * @param  int  $total
     * @param  int  $perPage
     * @param  int  $currentPage
     * @param  array  $options
     * @return \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator
     */
    protected static function paginator($items, $total, $perPage, $currentPage, $options)
    {
        return Container::getInstance()->makeWith(LengthAwarePaginator::class, compact(
            'items', 'total', 'perPage', 'currentPage', 'options'
        ));
    }
}
```

and then use it:

```
use App\CustomClasses\ColectionPaginate;
...
$result = $query->limit(100)->get();
$paginatedResult = ColectionPaginate::paginate($result, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

****Solved**
**To Clarify the solution from above**
Change...

```
$user_dispatches = Dispatch::all()->where('user_id', Auth::id())->paginate(10);
```

to

```
$user_dispatches = Dispatch::where('user_id', Auth::id())->paginate(10)
```

**In another project** I was attempting to return a view with my posts array and I was also able to paginate like this...In PostController

```
public function index()
{
  $posts = Post::where('user_id', Auth::id());
  return view('admin.posts.index', ['posts'=>$posts->paginate(5)]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If working on laravel + Blade there's a case when I need to keep the `all()` or `get()` what I do is to add a `toQuery()` function to make it work. In my case, this snippet of code helped me get the pagination on Blade without changing my index function:

```
public function index()
  {
    $users = User::all();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
      //some code I need
      }
    }

    return view('users.index', ['users' => $users->toQuery()->paginate(5)]);
  }
```