# Laravel pagination relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-api

I asked to create a page that displays a list of all the categories and the last 3 products for each category.

There is a relationship between the category and the products.

I am trying to generate a route that will return a Json response.

Here is my code:

```
$category = Category::all()->load(["products"=>function($res){
            $res->take(3);
        }]);
        return $category->paginate(2);
```

But It returns an error:`Collection::paginate does not exist.`

What does it mean?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Method paginate does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48148472/laravel-method-paginate-does-not-exist)

Comment: Try removing "all()" because you cant paginate a collection

Comment: @RicardoJesusJarquinPerez thank you it's work!
But now the Pagination meta data is missing from the output.

Answer (score 1):

`all` method returns collection instead of query builder instance. You may use `with` instead of `load` and use `paginate` to get the paginated result:

```
return Category::with(["products" => function($res) {
    $res->take(3);
}])->paginate(2);
```

Please note that according to [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads):

> The `limit` and `take` query builder methods may not be used when constraining eager loads.

Comment: Thank you but it returns only the products that related to the first category

Comment: @Jack I added a note.

Comment: @Jack you may use this workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53022451/3477084