# Laravel limit with paginate

Tags: php, laravel

Do you know why I receive all the records with this query :

```
$pictures = Picture::latest()->limit(100)->paginate(18);
```

I should only get 100, but he gives them all to me
It's probably a parameter I'm forgetting but it doesn't seem illogical to me

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no easy solution for what you want so I suggest leaving it as is and allowing users to view all pages. There is no performance hit for doing so and it is a single line of code vs multiple and learning new concepts like custom paginations etc.

Answer (score 3):

The paginate query builder overrides your limit method.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results

> **Paginating Query Builder Results**
> The paginate method automatically takes care of setting the query's
> "limit" and "offset" based on the current page being viewed by the
> user.

Comment: Oh ok I see, but you have a solution for that or no ?

Comment: Pagination is generally used to allow the user to traverse the whole data collection. You can filter the collection by applying conditions to the `where` statement. This will limit the data the user can traverse.

Comment: To explain the situation, it's a photo feed, basically I display the last photos posted during the day and if there are no photos I would like to display the last 100

Comment: I updated my answer please check if this works

Comment: Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::paginate does not exist.

Comment: Did you use the Db facade or the Model? Could you try `Photo::take(100)->get()` and then `paginate()` ?

Comment: Same error. Look the third answer here, I think it's the cause : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48148472/laravel-method-paginate-does-not-exist

Comment: @Kylian collections don't have the paginate method. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50226837/487813) for how to create a custom paginator based on a collection result

Comment: Ok thanks for you help Apokryfos & ImAtWar ;) Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

```
$pictures = Picture::latest()->simplePaginate(18);
```

Try simplePaginate() instead.